# Is there a way to install packages in a Jupyter notebook and not have to reload them every time I open the notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, installation, folium, geopy

I am working on a notebook and it involved geopy and folium. The packages take a while to install. Whenever I close my computer and open it back up again, I have to refresh the page to reconnect to the kernel (maybe that's a separate issue). After the page refreshes and I try and run a folium map, it doesn't recognize that I've already installed the package and I have to do it all over again. I'm very new to this field, so what am I missing?

Comment: Could you please include example of your code and the error message?

Comment: After some googling, I used...                                                                                  `import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} -c conda-forge geopy
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} -c conda-forge folium=0.5.0`                                  But that didn't seem to do the trick. I still receive a 'no moduel" error

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment by any chance?

Comment: I am not using a virtual environment

Comment: Can you please add the actual error traceback to the original post?

Comment: How have you installed the packages?

Comment: @pavel <ipython-input-4-5ab33bfc5249> in <module>

Comment: @sentence by using !conda install etc...

Comment: Please, provide the output from `conda list`. Thanks.